# JavaScript: Remove all members from an old Facebook Group in bulk

Tags: javascript, facebook, google-chrome, facebook-javascript-sdk, bulk

I am the admin of a several-years-old Facebook group that has since been overrun by scam accounts (700 or so of them). There are far too many members for me to, realistically, manually remove them - as Facebook recommends.

Here is the link to the group:
https://www.facebook.com/groups/101697209943412

I understand that many websites offer JavaScript to perform member removal in bulk; however, I also understand that most of these scripts are toxic and can give control of your page to their developers/other people.

I thought I'd ask StackOverflow for a clean batch of code, in hopes that the community here has more integrity than the internet at large.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var j = 4;
function kickAll() {
   document.getElementsByClassName("_55pe")[j].click();
   setTimeout(function() { document.getElementsByClassName("_54nh")[1].click(); }, 3500);
   setTimeout(function() { document.getElementsByClassName("_42ft _4jy0 layerConfirm uiOverlayButton _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy")[0].click(); }, 6000);
   j++;
   setTimeout(function() { wait(); }, 10000);
}

function wait() {
   if(document.getElementsByClassName("_42ft _4jy0 layerConfirm uiOverlayButton _4jy3 _4jy1 selected _51sy")[0] == undefined) { kickAll(); }
   else { document.getElementsByClassName("_54nh")[1].click(); wait(); }
}

kickAll();
```

Also, when in the console you might get an error 'document is not defined', if so, check that the top-left dropdown box is set to '`<top frame>`'

Comment: All it outputs is an integer (1, then 2 if I copy-paste into the console a second time).

Comment: If you trust me, you could add me as an admin to the page so I can test it myself and work out any problems. It's a bit iffy to write code like this

Comment: Sure - ask to join and I'll let you in.

Comment: It's not like you can mess the group up any more than it already is :P I trust you!